# Simple react component - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am following a book 'Learn React with TypeScript' and I have finished chapter 3 but I can't seem to get my program to compile properly. I am just creating a simple confirm component with buttons.

> ERROR: ./src/Confirm.tsx   Line 20:3:  Expected an assignment or
>   function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

I feel like I have written the code correctly, could anyone point me in the right direction please? :)

App.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Confirm.css';
import Confirm from './Confirm';

class App extends Component {

  private handleCancelConfirmClick = () => {
    console.log("Cancel clicked");
  }

  private handleOkConfirmClick = () => {
    console.log("Cancel clicked");
  }  

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Confirm
          title="React and TypeScript"
          content="Are you sure you want to learn?"
          cancelCaption="No way"
          okCaption="Yes please!"
          onCancelClick={this.handleCancelConfirmClick}
          onOkClick={this.handleOkConfirmClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Confirm.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Iprops {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    cancelCaption?: string;
    okCaption?: string;
    onOkClick: () => void;
    onCancelClick: () => void;
}

class Confirm extends React.Component<Iprops> {

    public static defaultProps = {
        cancelCaption: "Cancel",
        okCaption: "Okay"
    }

    private handleOkClick = () => {
        this.props.onOkClick;
    }

    private handleCancelClick = () => {
        this.props.onCancelClick;
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className="confirm-wrapper confirm-visible">
                <div className="confirm-container">
                    <div className="confirm-title-container">
                        <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="confirm-content-container">
                        <p>{this.props.content}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="confirm-buttons-container">
                        <button className="confirm-cancel" onClick={this.handleCancelClick}>
                            {this.props.cancelCaption}
                        </button>
                        <button className="confirm-ok" onClick={this.handleOkClick}>
                            {this.props.okCaption}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Confirm;
```

Comment: typo: `this.props.onOkClick` and `this.props.onCancelClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call a method with parentheses, such as write

```
private handleOkClick = () => {
        this.props.onOkClick;
    }
```

as

```
private handleOkClick = () => {
        this.props.onOkClick();
    }
```

Comment: Omg thank you! That fixed it. No syntax errors were showing in my code... but yeah thanks a bunch :D

Comment: if that helped you then accept this answer and upvote it

Comment: I did upvote and had to wait 6 minutes untill accepting it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The handlers { handleOkClick ,handleCancelClick }  have function calls passed as props, so call it as  **this.props.onOkClick()** rather than  ***this.props.onOkClick;***

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Iprops {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    cancelCaption?: string;
    okCaption?: string;
    onOkClick: () => void;
    onCancelClick: () => void;
}

class Confirm extends React.Component<Iprops> {

    public static defaultProps = {
    cancelCaption: "Cancel",
    okCaption: "Okay"
    }

    private handleOkClick = () => {
        this.props.onOkClick();
    }

    private handleCancelClick = () => {
        this.props.onCancelClick();
    }

    public render() {
        return (
        <div className="confirm-wrapper confirm-visible">
        <div className="confirm-container">
            <div className="confirm-title-container">
                <span>{this.props.title}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="confirm-content-container">
                <p>{this.props.content}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="confirm-buttons-container">
                <button className="confirm-cancel" onClick={this.handleCancelClick}>
                    {this.props.cancelCaption}
                </button>
                <button className="confirm-ok" onClick={this.handleOkClick}>
                    {this.props.okCaption}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Confirm;
```